# RNN Slow-down phenomenon of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, slice, lstm

I found a peculiar property of lstm cell(not limited to lstm but I only examined with this) of tensorflow which has not been reported as far as I know.
I don't know whether it actually has, so I left this post in SO. Below is a toy code for this problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

def network(input_list):
    input,init_hidden_c,init_hidden_m = input_list
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(256, state_is_tuple=True)
    init_hidden = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(init_hidden_c, init_hidden_m)
    states, hidden_cm = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, input, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=init_hidden)
    net = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
    return states, hidden_cm, net

def action(x, h_c, h_m):
    t0 = time.time()
    outputs, output_h = sess.run([rnn_states[:,-1:,:], rnn_hidden_cm], feed_dict={
        rnn_input:x,
        rnn_init_hidden_c: h_c,
        rnn_init_hidden_m: h_m
    })
    dt = time.time() - t0
    return outputs, output_h, dt

rnn_input = tf.placeholder("float", [None, None, 512])
rnn_init_hidden_c = tf.placeholder("float", [None,256])
rnn_init_hidden_m = tf.placeholder("float", [None,256])
rnn_input_list = [rnn_input, rnn_init_hidden_c, rnn_init_hidden_m]
rnn_states, rnn_hidden_cm, rnn_net = network(rnn_input_list)

feed_input = np.random.uniform(low=-1.,high=1.,size=(1,1,512))
feed_init_hidden_c = np.zeros(shape=(1,256))
feed_init_hidden_m = np.zeros(shape=(1,256))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(10000):
    _, output_hidden_cm, deltat = action(feed_input, feed_init_hidden_c, feed_init_hidden_m)
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print 'Running time: ' + str(deltat)
    (feed_init_hidden_c, feed_init_hidden_m) = output_hidden_cm
    feed_input = np.random.uniform(low=-1.,high=1.,size=(1,1,512))
```

[Not important]What this code does is to generate an output from 'network()' function containing LSTM where the input's temporal dimension is 1, so output's is also 1, and pull in&out initial state for each step of running.

[Important] Looking the 'sess.run()' part. For some reasons in my real code, I happened to put [:,-1:,:] for 'rnn_states'. What is happening is then **the time spent for each 'sess.run()' increases**. For some inspection by my own, I found this slow down stems from that [:,-1:,:]. I just wanted to get the output at the last time step. If you do 'outputs, output_h = sess.run([rnn_states, rnn_hidden_cm], feed_dict{~' w/o [:,-1:,:] and take 'last_output = outputs[:,-1:,:]' after the 'sess.run()', then the slow down does not occur.

I do not know why this exponential increment of time happens with that [:,-1:,:] running. Is this the nature of tensorflow hasn't been documented but particularly slows down(may be adding more graph by its own?)?
Thank you, and hope this mistake not happen for other users by this post.

Comment: You just need to move that slicing to be outside the for loop.

Comment: @Aaron: I guess 'for' loop is not the point. 'action()' outputs the 'output' at the last temporal-step of the 'outputs' and I issued whether that slicing out the last one 'output' from the 'outputs' can be made within the 'sess.run()' - which turned out to be problematic - or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, with TensorFlow slowing down for each iteration I ran it, and found this question while trying to debug it. Here's a short description of my situation and how I solved it for future reference. Hopefully it can point someone in the right direction and save them some time.

In my case the problem was mainly that I didn't make use of `feed_dict` to supply the network state when executing `sess.run()`. Instead I redeclared `outputs`, `final_state` and `prediction` every iteration. The answer at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1439#issuecomment-194405649 made me realize how stupid that was... I was constantly creating new graph nodes in every iteration, making it all slower and slower. The problematic code looked something like this:

```
# defining the network
lstm_layer = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units, forget_bias=1)
outputs, final_state = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_layer, input, initial_state=rnn_state, dtype='float32')
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(outputs[-1], out_weights)+out_bias)

for input_data in data_seq:
    # redeclaring, stupid stupid...
    outputs, final_state = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_layer, input, initial_state=rnn_state, dtype='float32')
    prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(outputs[-1], out_weights)+out_bias)
    p, rnn_state = sess.run((prediction, final_state), feed_dict={x: input_data})
```

The solution was of course to only declare the nodes once in the beginning, and supply the new data with `feed_dict`. The code went from being half slow (> 15 ms in the beginning) and becoming slower for every iteration, to execute every iteration in around 1 ms. My new code looks something like this:

```
out_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_units, n_classes]), name="out_weights")
out_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]), name="out_bias")

# placeholder for the network state
state_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, 1, num_units])
rnn_state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(state_placeholder[0], state_placeholder[1])

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 1, n_input])
input = tf.unstack(x, 1, 1)

# defining the network
lstm_layer = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units, forget_bias=1)
outputs, final_state = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_layer, input, initial_state=rnn_state, dtype='float32')

prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(outputs[-1], out_weights)+out_bias)

# actual network state, which we input with feed_dict
_rnn_state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(np.zeros((1, num_units), dtype='float32'), np.zeros((1, num_units), dtype='float32'))

it = 0
for input_data in data_seq:
    encl_input = [[input_data]]
    p, _rnn_state = sess.run((prediction, final_state), feed_dict={x: encl_input, rnn_state: _rnn_state})
    print("{} - {}".format(it, p))
    it += 1
```

Moving the declaration out from the for loop also got rid of the problem which the OP sdr2002 had, doing a slice `outputs[-1]` in `sess.run()` inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, no sliced output for 'sess.run()' is much appreciated for this case.

```
def action(x, h_c, h_m):
    t0 = time.time()
    outputs, output_h = sess.run([rnn_states, rnn_hidden_cm], feed_dict={
        rnn_input:x,
        rnn_init_hidden_c: h_c,
        rnn_init_hidden_m: h_m
    })
    outputs = outputs[:,-1:,:]
    dt = time.time() - t0
    return outputs, output_h, dt
```